# Duplicate Eclipse workspace with projects

Tags: eclipse, workspace

I just want to know if there is a way to duplicate an eclipse workspace **including the projects inside.**

EDIT : Copying files doesn't work for me, I'm looking for an automated process or a plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any automated solution. The worskpace itself (in the `.metadata` directory) contains absolute paths and that's the reason why you cannot simply copy it.

I always duplicate workspace by creating a new one. It may be more complicated, but it always works. I have all the eclipse-project files (`.settings` directory) in a versioning system which makes creating brand new workspace relatively simple. After creating empty workspace, I just use `Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace`.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly copying a workspace, but you mentioned what you are looking for is an automated process, so [Eclipse Installer](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Installer) (a.k.a. [Oomph](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.oomph)) might be an option. It allows you to provision  developer workspaces including cloning VCS repositories, setting up projects and pre-setting user preferences. The [Eclipse Launcher](https://www.yatta.de/profiles) by [Yatta](https://www.yatta.de), which extends Oomph, might also be interesting to you.

Answer (score -1):

Yes if your eclipse versions match up. You can do it by straight filesystem copy. If its not same then metadata may create loading issue.

Comment: I've already tried this method but I have a very specific file architecture and just copy files doesn't work. I want to know if there is an automated way or plugin that could help me.

Comment: That does not work, the new (copy) workspace opens the files of the original workspace.